# Method GET Django and Angular error 500 internal server

Tags: django, angular

I'm building a basic app with login, register, etc. now i try finish the login using Django like backend and fronted with Angular, but i can't end my login because this error, when i try login with  the correct credentials and redirect to new page or url show this error.

[TypeError at /doctor
'list' object is not callable"in network panel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grM70.png)

service .ts

```
constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    getDoctores(): Promise<Doctor[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/doctor?format=json', { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Doctor[])
    }
```

component .ts

```
 constructor(private dataService: dataService, public dialog: MatDialog,
        private router: Router) {
    this.getDoctores();
    this.selectedDoctor = {
      id: -1, nombreDoc: '', apellidoDoc: '', rutDoc: '', direccionDoc: ''
      , telefonoDoc: '', release_date: ''
    }
  }
  getDoctores(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getDoctores()
      .then(doctores => this.doctores = doctores);
  }
```

url.py

```
    path('auth/login/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('auth/refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^doctor$', views.DoctorList.as_view()),
    url(r'^doctor/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.DoctorDetail.as_view()),
```

view.py

```
class DoctorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer

class DoctorDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer
```

Comment: Show the full Django error, and the code of DoctorSerializer.

Comment: can be the "[]" no "()" ? in serializer?

Comment: **from rest_framework import serializers
from LABORATORIO.models import Doctor, Paciente, Examen, Categoria
from django.contrib.auth.models import User**






class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('id',  'nombreDoc','apellidoDoc','rutDoc', 'direccionDoc','telefonoDoc','release_date')
`

Comment: Please post that as an edit to the question, properly formatted.

Comment: Did you add the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST on settings?

Comment: @NoahLc do you mean Angular url? yes

Comment: @jimroot I mean
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost/'
) in your settings.py

Comment: @NoahLc yes and same error